# Farsi: why letter Alef often sounds like long "o"?

Tags: persian

Gday, everyone. I'm a beginner in the Persian language.

Why letter Alef often sounds like long "o"? For example, in the word "air" - هوا - havaa.
If I listen to examples, say, on https://www.persianpod101.com/persian-dictionary/ for هوا, what I hear is "havo". I'm expecting long "a" though... Can anyone tell me where I am wrong, or not wrong. Thanks!

Comment: [Anton, the question form in English is: **Why does the letter Alef** sound like etc.]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a language-specific grammar question.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine 1. it's not, and 2. those aren't necessarily off-topic either. They're only off-topic if they're just about learning the language, not if they're about observing phenomena in a language's grammar.

Comment: Many people actually pronounce it more like "oo" in "school" and this is also being reflected in (colloquial) writing, e.g. خونه instead of خانه.

Comment: As a native Persian speaker I listened to the word هوا in your linked website and I heared a long "a".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The long *ā* in Persian is realised further back than the short *a*, typically as  [ɑː] or [ɒː] compared to [a] or [æ]. As you can see on the IPA vowel chart, that puts it closer to typical *o* sounds:

[image: IPA vowel chart]

(In fact, [ɑ] or [ɒ] are exactly the sounds used in English for certain *o* sounds, in words like *lot* and *cloth*, though the details vary by dialect.)

It's not unusual for languages with (current or historical) distinctions in vowel length to also distinguish those vowels by quality: in Dutch, for instance, short *a* is [ɑ] and long *ā* is [aː], the reverse situation. Usually short vowels tend to be more back and long vowels more front in those cases, but the reverse also happens.

Comment: And in Hungarian, short /a/ is [ɒ] (or even [ɔ]), while long /aː/ is [aː].

Comment: To be a bit more precise: in modern Persian /ɒ/ is not longer than /a/. The distinction is in quality, not quantity.

Comment: Thanks for that response. I find it confusing that in the various lessons available online, the teachers overly focus on Alef being a long 'a' sound. And when they themselves sometimes shift it towards 'o', they leave it uncommented. And here I was, left guessing and puzzled :)